# PHP SQLSRV return JSON

Tags: php, json, sqlsrv

I am using a SQL Server database, so I am getting adjusted to the syntax.

I am trying to return some JSON, but I cannot seem to get the formatting correct.

In my PHP script, I have this code below:

```
 <?php
   $select = "SELECT
                CONCAT('\"',COALESCE('',''),'\"') AS EDIT
                ,CONCAT('\"',COALESCE([FOR_PARTNER],''),'\"') AS PARTNER_CODE
                ,CONCAT('\"',COALESCE([FOR_NAME],''),'\"') AS PARTNER_NAME
                ,CONCAT('\"',COALESCE([SHP_PARTNER],''),'\"') AS SHIPPER_PCODE
                ,CONCAT('\"',COALESCE([SHP_NAME],''),'\"') AS SHIPPER_NAME
                ,CONCAT('\"',COALESCE([MODDATE],''),'\"') AS MODDATE
                ,CONCAT('\"',COALESCE([MODUSER],''),'\"') AS MODUSER
                ,CONCAT('\"',COALESCE([ID],''),'\"') AS ID
             FROM
                [main].[dbo].[exceptions]";

 $query = sqlsrv_query($dbc, $select);
 $resnum = sqlsrv_num_rows($query);

 // here is where the error lies

 echo "{\"data\":[";
 $i = 1;    
 while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
   echo "[";
     echo implode(', ', $row);
   echo "]";
   if($i < $resnum){
     echo ",";
   }
   $i++;
 }
 echo "]}";

 sqlsrv_free_stmt($query);
 ?>
```

Using the above code, the JSON that is returned looks like this:

```
 {"data":[["", "0000111111", "JBR", "00000999999", "AMERICA INC", "Jan 1 1900 12:00AM", "", "55"]["", "0000777777", "7ALEXANDER LOG", "000222222", "NORRIS INC", "Jan 1 1900 12:00AM", "", "56"]]}
```

If you'll notice, there is no comma separating the inner array.  It should be returned like this:

```
 {"data":[["", "0000111111", "JBR", "00000999999", "AMERICA INC", "Jan 1 1900 12:00AM", "", "55"],["", "0000777777", "7ALEXANDER LOG", "000222222", "NORRIS INC", "Jan 1 1900 12:00AM", "", "56"]]}
```

I have used the same syntax with MySQL, but of course, that's MySQL.  I am using SQLSRV above.  I am not sure if the IMPLODE is understood this go around.

So in short, I need to get the comma to separate the inner array.

Does anyone see my error?

Comment: don't do that. don't build your own json. do a NORMAL query, return a NORMAL result set, then build a NATIVE php data stucture. Once that's done, you can do `json_encode()` on that structure, and your problem goes away. your version is obviously not working, and vulnerable to json injection attacks as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example for your code:

```
<?php

$select = "SELECT
            PARTNER_CODE, PARTNER_NAME, SHIPPER_PCODE, SHIPPER_NAME, MODDATE, MODUSER, ID
         FROM
            [main].[dbo].[exceptions]";

$query = sqlsrv_query($dbc, $select);
$res = [];

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {
// you need SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC for your result, but i prefere to use SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC
    $res[] = $row;
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($query);
echo json_encode( [ 'data' => $res ] );
```